# Canvas zooming in WPF using code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Here the scenario is:

I have a canvas with different diagrams drawn on it. Now the requirement is to zoom into the canvas using the code behind either using C# or VB. Moreover I need to place the zoom code in some dll so that i can reuse the same set of code through out my application.

Now my question is how to do this....

I have tried the following code pls have a look..

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    canvas.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(canvas_MouseEnter);
    canvas.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(canvas_MouseWheel);
}

void canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    double height = canvas.ActualHeight;
    double width = canvas.ActualWidth;
    double zoom = e.Delta;
    height += 2;
    width += 2;
    ScaleTransform sc = new ScaleTransform(width, height);
    canvas.LayoutTransform = sc;
    canvas.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should look up how to use a ScaleTransform, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Ya Eric.... I have tried the Scale Transform here is my code that i want to execute when my mouseWheel event is invoked...

Comment: <code>        double height = canvas.ActualHeight;
            double width = canvas.ActualWidth;

            double zoom = 5;

            height += zoom;
            width += zoom;

            
            canvas.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(height, width);
</Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a **zoom behavior**.  [Behaviors are objects that encapsulate some form of interactive behavior](https://web.archive.org/web/20151218211006/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dphill/archive/2009/09/25/blend-behaviors.aspx). I've seen several examples of "Zoom Behaviors" that you should be able to use for your project.  You should be able to use or modify one of the following...

- [Laurent Bugnion's Zoom Behavior](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124121801/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/04/05/using-a-behavior-to-magnify-your-wpf-applications.aspx)
- [WPF Extensions](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpfextensions) - has a zoom control

Comment: WPF Extensions has a excellent zoom control - fast and easy to use!

Answer (score 5):

Try to implement this sample:

```
    var canvas = new Canvas();
    var st = new ScaleTransform();
    var textBox = new TextBox {Text = "Test"};
    canvas.RenderTransform = st;
    canvas.Children.Add(textBox);
    canvas.MouseWheel += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            st.ScaleX *= 2;
            st.ScaleY *= 2;
        }
        else
        {
            st.ScaleX /= 2;
            st.ScaleY /= 2;
        }
    };
```

Comment: That was nice, thank you. I also scale the height and width of the canvas at the same rate so the zoom doesn't zoom the textbox out of the canvas.