# Zoom Video in WPF MediaElement

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, media-player

I like to zoom a video which I play with MediaElement to i.e. 150% but keep the MediaElement Size fixed. This should only show the center of the video on the screen i.e. like a wide screen movie on a 4:3 screen without black bars on the top and bottom.
How can I do this? I checked the MediaElement class and I didn’t find anything like zoom. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could also simply use a LayoutTransform (ScaleTransform).
An example is provided here: https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement/blob/master/Unosquare.FFME.Windows/Rendering/VideoRenderer.cs#L330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the media element to a canvas

```
                mediaelement.Width = canvas.Width;
                mediaelement.Height = canvas.Height;
                mediaelement.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
```

For zooming the canvas check the link
[Canvas zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952010/canvas-zooming-in-wpf-using-code-behind)

Comment: Thanks JTM, I looked at the Canvas zooming link you provided but they seemed relative complicated to me. I found this simple example:
WPF simple zoom and drag support in a ScrollViewer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97871/WPF-simple-zoom-and-drag-support-in-a-ScrollViewer
I added a MediaElement for testing and the zooming works fine. Problem solved!